# How to remove the last block of text between parentheses in a string, only if there are two blocks of text between parentheses at the end of string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to remove the last block of text between parentheses in a string, but only when there are two blocks of text between parentheses at the end of that string.

For instance, if the string is

```
Text (aaa) Text (bbb) Text (ccc) (ddd).
```

I need to get

```
Text (aaa) Text (bbb) Text (ccc).
```

While, if the string is

```
Text (aaa) Text (bbb) Text (ccc).
```

I need to preserve it as it is.

I've tried several regular expressions using [https://regexr.com](http://regexr.com/66a8d) (e.g. `/\s\(([^)]+)\)\s\(([^)]+)\)/`), but none of them is right for me (I'm not very experienced with regex).

Would you give me any suggestions?

Comment: And if there are three? Is there always `.` at the end? Or any non-word chars?

Comment: Yes, I'll give you a suggestion: define exactly what you mean by "block of text".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
text = text.replace(/(\([^()]*\))\s*\([^()]*\)(?![\s\S]*\([^()]*\))/, '$1')
// Or, if there is always a dot and end of string (with possible trailing whitespace)
text = text.replace(/(\([^()]*\))\s*\([^()]*\)(?=\.\s*$)/, '$1')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/f5m8JD/3). *Details*:

- `(\([^()]*\))` - Group 1 (`$1`): `(`, zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` and then a `)` char
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\([^()]*\)` - `(`, zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` and then a `)` char
- `(?![\s\S]*\([^()]*\))` - a negative lookahead that ensures there is no other `(...)` substring anywhere to the right of the current location.
- `(?=\.\s*$)` - a positive lookahead that requires `.`, then zero or more whitespaces and then an end of string immediately to the right of the current location.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
const texts = ['Text (aaa) Text (bbb) Text (ccc) (ddd).','Text (aaa) Text (bbb) Text (ccc).'];
const rx = /(\([^()]*\))\s*\([^()]*\)(?![\s\S]*\([^()]*\))/;
for (const text of texts) {
    console.log(text, '=>', text.replace(rx, '$1'));
}
```

Comment: Woh wonderful answer